# Count date strings between a range of dates

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table (table_1). In that table, one of the columns is called 'date'. Values in that column are 'string' type and in the format 'yyyyMMdd', (ex: 20210102). I am trying to get the count(*) of records of a range of dates in that column.

Ex: select count(*) from table_1 where date BETWEEN 20210101 AND 20210301. This will not work now since that column is 'string' type. Need some help querying the DATE version of that column.

Comment: Why can't you parse the string into a date type that supports `BETWEEN` on other date types?

Comment: Alternatively, `WHERE date BETWEEN '20210101' AND '20210301'` should work fine for `yyyyMMdd` formatted values (you need the quotes)

Comment: I prefer casting them by myself than trusting hive so pls use - select count(*) from table_1 where cast(`date` as BIGINT) BETWEEN 20210101 AND 20210301

Comment: If the question is how to convert to date: `
    date(regexp_replace(date_col,'^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$','$1-$2-$3'))` But for filtering only you do not need any conversion, just replace yous numbers with the same strings - enclose in quotes and it will work fine